# Assembler code, error C2443: operand size conflict

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to write some simple asm code but I get this error:
error C2443: operand size conflict

I want to multiply 2 numbers and then move the result to another variable...

My teacher wrote this code:

```
int main()
{unsigned char x,y;

_asm{
    mov ax,3
    mov bx,5
    mul bx
    mov y,ax

}
cout<<y<<"\n";
}
```

From what I understood, ax uses only 16bits...
But unsigned char is 8bits in size? If I use ah or al (8bit) it won't do 3*5 at all BUT I have no errors. I am very confused... How do I work with ax and bx and move the result to y without getting errors?

Comment: So, like, uh, how about *asking your teacher*? If you got code that didn't work, from a teacher, isn't that something you'd better point out?

Comment: Similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626384/612920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The declaration should be:

```
unsigned short x,y;
```

`cout` will convert `unsigned short` to a decimal number (ASCII) while `unsigned char` will be interpreted as ASCII character and left unconverted (at least on my system).

Answer (score 0):

You can mul at 8 bit register as well 
    `mov     al, '3'
    sub     al, '0'
    mov     bl, '5'
    sub     bl, '0'
    mul     bl`

'3' is ASCII code for 3  if you sub '0' ASCII code you'll have 3 in your register(same with '5'). 
Otherwise you can use `short` variables.